# useEffect do not work in context api in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm an student studying React. I'm making a project that I use functional React, hook.
When I used `context` api in class type react, `componentDidmount` is working in provider. But, when i use functional react in `context`, `useEffect` is not working! how can i fix it? Thank you so much!

BoardContext.js

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

const BoardContext = createContext();

export default BoardContext;
```

BoardProvider.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import BoardContext from './BoardContext';

const BoardProvider = ({ children }) => {
  console.log('1. is working!!');
  const [categoryData, setCategoryData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('is not working in useEffect  ');
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    console.log('not working');
    const { data } = await axios('/data/categoryData.json');
    console.log(data);

    setCategoryData(data);
  };

  console.log('is working!');

  return (
    <BoardContext.Provider value={{ categoryData }}>
      {children}
    </BoardContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default BoardProvider;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Routes from './Routes';
import GlobalStyle from './Styles/GlobalStyles';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import BoardProvider from './BoardProvider';
import theme from './Styles/theme';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BoardProvider>
    <GlobalStyle />
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Routes />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </BoardProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The code looks fine at first sight. Is there any output or error after the logs shown?

Comment: I have just uploaded next error!

Comment: Can you show us TagModalCategory component or the one where you added `const {categoryData} = useContext(BoardContext)`

Comment: Well, your app is crashing during the first render. As effects are called **after** render they will not run. The error indicates, that you are trying to access a variable `categoryData` in `TagModelCategory.js` that is not defined. Did you forget to use `useContext`?

Comment: Oh my! I didn't know that! I fixed this problem. Thank you so much! I will study more about life cycle!

Comment: It will be great if you could post how you fixed it as an answer below.

Comment: Ok! I will post how to solve this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
As early mentioned, I was changing structure so that class type context api turn into functional context api.
So I commented out below one line! I didn't know that useEffect is affected by useContext in other Component. Because I thought that useEffect will render firstly, so below line is affected later. Actually, I can not understand order when component execute!

```
TagModalCategory.js
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import theme from '../../Styles/theme';
import BoardContext from '../../BoardContext';

const TagModalCategory = () => {
  //const { categoryData, handleSelector } = useContext(BoardContext);
// because of this comment! I commented out this line! when I delete this comment, the issue was solved!

  const hanldeSelector = id => {
    handleSelector(id);
  };

  const genColor = () => {
    const hexNumber = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
    let result = '#';
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * hexNumber.length);
      result += hexNumber[randomColor];
    }
    return result;
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <CategoryModalContainer>
        <h3>
          Hello!
        </h3>
        <h3>1.choose Category</h3>
        <CategoryItemContainer>
          {categoryData.map(category => {
            return (
              <CategoryItem
                key={category.id}
                genColor={genColor}
                onClick={() => hanldeSelector(category.id)}
              >
                {category.name}
              </CategoryItem>
            );
          })}
        </CategoryItemContainer>
      </CategoryModalContainer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TagModalCategory;

const CategoryModalContainer = styled.div`
  margin: 20px;
`;
const CategoryItemContainer = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 0.5fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 0.5fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
`;
const CategoryItem = styled.button`
  ${theme.categoryStyle}
  background-color: ${props => props.genColor};
`;
```